# Selenium java. How to get text in a span?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How do I get a text from the span tag with Selenium Java from this:

[image]

I try this code:

```
WebElement c = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/span"));
final String text = c.getText();
System.out.println("this is text from span => " + text);
```

But the output is an empty string...

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image, instead, edit the question by posting it in text format. You should take a look at [ask] and take the tour, if you have not done so already. Also take a look at minimal reproducible example. This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

`"//div[1]/span"` is xpath for the first span of the first div in the page.

If there is no other element with id "posto-rencana", this will work:

```
WebElement c = webDriver.findElement(By.id("posto-rencana"));
final String text = c.getText(); // don't see reason for final,
System.out.println("this is text from span => " + text);
```

You can use dynamic xpath as well, see https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/

```
"//span[@class='ul-widget__number_text-success']"
```

Comment: not worked..
T.T

Comment: are there multiple elements with the id "posto-rencana"?  if not, the search via Id should work...also, are there multiple elements with the "card" class name? if so, then you should post the full html file